# Existence of a composition series in a commutative finite group

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Let $G$ be a commutative group. Then
>   $G$ has a composition series if and only if $G$ is finite.

I have read some proof regarding the converse: If $G$ is finite, then $G$ has a composition series.
However, I don't have idea on the implication. Any help please. Thanks.

Comment: There are infinite simple groups; $A_\infty$ for example.  Wouldn't this be an infinite group with a composition series (of length $1$)?

Comment: @Jim I don't think that group is abelian.

Comment: Hurr... I missed the commutative condition, lol.  My bad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a sketch.

A composition series is in particular a subnormal series of a finite length. Each composition factor must be a simple abelian group, and hence must be finite and of prime order. Using induction and Lagrange's theorem, you can show the order of the group must be the product of the orders of its composition factors. The theorem follows immediately.